# Hadoop Map Reduce queries for large key spaces

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to process one billion of records periodically. The unique keys can be in range of 10 millions. Value is string with maximum 200K chars.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the key space very large (10 millions). Would Hadoop be able to handle such a large key space? There will be one reducer per key, so there will be millions of reducers.
2. I want to update the DB in the reducer itself. In the reducer, I will merge the values (say it current value), read existing value from DB (say it existing value), merge current and existing value and update the DB. Is this a right strategy?
3. How many reducers can run per box simultaneously? Is it configurable?  If only a single reducer runs per box at a time, it will be problem, as I won't be able to update the state for keys in DB very fast.
4. I want the job to get completed in 2-3 hours. How many boxes would I need ( I can spare max 50 boxes - 64 GB RAM, 8 Core machines)

Thanks

Comment: How does the merge implemented?  Does every key necessarily cause a data base update or in practice is it only a subset?  What's that logic look like at a high level?

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, every key may not necessarily mean a database update, but I am not counting on that. In practice, I can have a scenario where I need to update the DB for every key. You can assume that it is like updating the state for a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

a. You have got the wrong concept of Key,Value distribution among reducers. Number of reducers isn't equal to the number of unique mapper output keys.
The concept is - all the values associated to a key from mapper goes to a single reducer. This in no way means that a reducer will get only one key.

For example, consider the following mapper outputs:

```
Mapper(k1,v1), Mapper(k1,v2), Mapper(k1,v3)
Mapper(k2,w1), Mapper(k2,w2)
Mapper(k3,u1), Mapper(k3,u2), Mapper(k3,u3), Mapper(k3,u4)
```

So, the values related to *k1 - v1,v2* and *v3* will go into a single reducer, say *R1*, and it won't get split up into multiple reducers. But it doesn't mean that R1 would have only 1 key *k1* to process. It may have values of *k2* or *k3* also. But for any key that a reducer receives, all the values associated to that key will come to the same reducer. Hope it clears your doubt.

b. Which DB are you using? To reduce DB calls or update statements, you can have your query at the end of the reducer() after the looping through the values related to a particular key is complete.

For example:

```
public static class ReduceJob extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public synchronized void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


            while (values.hasNext()) {
                      // looping through the values
            }
            // have your DB update etc. query here to reduce DB calls
      }
}
```

c. Yes, the number of reducers are configurable. If you want to set it per job basis, you can add a line in your job code run() method which sets the number of reducers.

```
jobConf.set("mapred.reduce.tasks", numReducers)
```

If you want to set it per machine basis, i.e. how many reducers each machine in your cluster should have, then you need to change the hadoop configuration of your cluster as:

> mapred.tasktracker.{map|reduce}.tasks.maximum - The maximum number of
>   MapReduce tasks, which are run simultaneously on a given TaskTracker,
>   individually. Defaults to 2 (2 maps and 2 reduces), but vary it
>   depending on your hardware.

More details here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html#Configuring+the+Hadoop+Daemons

d. If your data files are not gZipped(hadoop InputSplit does not work with gZipped files), then as per what you said, you have 200 * 1024 * 1 billion bytes = 204800 GB or 204.800 TB data approx, so if you want to get it completed in 2-3 hours, better spare all the 50 boxes and if the memory footprint of the reducer is low, then increase the number of reducers per machine as per last answer. Also, increasing the InputSplit size to around 128MB might help.

Thanks and Regards.
Kartikeya Sinha

Comment: Hi Kartikeya,
Thanks a lot. There are some follow up qns:

Comment: a. That clears my doubt. Assume that I have to process 10 million keys in 2 hours of reducing jobs with 50 hosts, processing of key takes half seconds (it's more of multiple DB calls). This means I need to process 28 keys/second per box. If only a single reducer is running per box, we can't achieve that. I want to run 30 reducers per box.  
b. I will have queries at the end. Is it a bad strategy to make updates from reducer?
c. I want to set it per box. How big this number can be? What are the things that we need to keep in mind to calculate this?
d. In practice, I expect it to be much less.

Comment: e. Do you see any problem due to this large key space (like shuffling, etc)